# Function not getting called

Tags: c#, function

I'm in trouble with some of my code,
I want to call a method but the method does not get called and I do not know why.

```
    var rows = GetDataGridRows(dgTickets);
    int intTickets = 0;
    foreach (System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow r in rows)
    { 
        //some code
    } 

    private IEnumerable<System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow>
               GetDataGridRows(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid grid)
    {
       var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
       if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
       foreach (var item in itemsSource)
       {
           var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item)
                                 as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow;
           if (null != row) yield return row;
       }
    }
```

`var rows = GetDataGridRows(dgTickets);` doesn't call the function and just go to `int intTickets = 0`

I have no idea what to do

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you pressing F10 or F11 ? Can you elaborate on does not call the function

Comment: Have you made sure that the call doesn't happen using break point and stepping through the code? Or are you saying it doesn't get called because you don't get the desired output?

Comment: How do you know that `GetDataGridRows` isn't being called? Did you put a breakpoint in it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method `GetDataGridRows` returns an `IEnumerable` using `yield`. It's not until your `foreach` block is executed that you'll step into this method.

The use of the `yield` keyword allows the C# compiler to use it's state machine generator to create an implementation of `IEnumerable` which it returns. `IEnumerable` use lazy invocation, which essentially means it's only interated when it is required. This is where you see it jumping over the declaration to the next step, because at that point, it is only an instance of `IEnuemrable` which has yet to be cycled through.

Comment: Yes, I see it, but he doesn't fill my 'rows' and on another place in my code I also use that function and there it works

Comment: @user735646 In that case, I would say you are possibly calling the code at the wrong time...e.g., are you calling it before the grid is populated with data?

Comment: No the itemssource of the grid contains 13 items

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use...

```
table_id.DataSource = GetDataGridRows(dgTickets);
table_id.DataBind();
```